# Pass session cookies from javascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session-cookies

I would like to pass session variable from javascript. The problem that the Javascript itself was generated from PHP

```
echo "<script>"
."if(confirm('Evaluation is already exist! Do you want to update evaluation?'))
  {
    //Here I want to add : $_SESSION['confirmed']=1; so I can proceed to save process
    alert('Evaluation Saved!);
  }
  else
  {
     alert('Evaluation Cancelled!);
  }"
    ."</script>";
```

How can I make this work ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't works that way - you'd need to create/update the session with JS or send an ajax request to a php file that would to it.

Comment: do you want to set session when page is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about making ajax calls and passing the session cookie in the header then you donot need to do this manually, since all the ajax calls made to the same domain shall already have all the respective cookies.

But if you are making ajax calls from different domain then it won't have the session cookie. Since AJAX calls only send cookies if the url you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to store session variable

```
echo "<script>"
."if(confirm('Evaluation is already exist! Do you want to update evaluation?'))
  {
    $.post( '/setsessionvariable.php', function(){
      alert('Evaluation Saved!);
    });

  }
  else
  {
     alert('Evaluation Cancelled!);
  }"
    ."</script>";
```

and in setsessionvariable.php file

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['confirmed'] = 1;
```

Comment: in setsessionvariable.php file?

Comment: Yes it is. nothing in 'confirmed'

Comment: Wont it always give 1 for confirmed? and the alert is not working

Answer (score -1):

One thing I should say. you cant able to create SESSION using java script. since SESSION  will run on server side. js will run in front end(browser). or use AJAX for passing a variable. Try this code hepls to solve your problem.

```
   <?php
session_start();
$confirmed=1;
if($confirmed==1){
    $_SESSION['confirmed']=1;
    echo "<script> alert('Evaluation Saved!'); </script>";
  }

  else
  {
session_destroy();// to destory existing session
     echo "<script> alert('Evaluation Cancelled!'); </script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I didnt get the value of confirmed

Comment: @Elbert alter. if(confirm('Evaluation is already exist! Do you want to update evaluation?')){}. chage if condition properly

Comment: ok you try the answer and say. have you got idea on seeing the code